# Reading a HTML file from web content folder in Servlet

Tags: servlets, resources, webcontent

I am trying to read an .html file from war file. I have used the code below, but it does not work.

Project structure:

```
Project
|_war
    |_Pages
      |_HtmlFiles
        |_sample.html
```

My code:

```
InputStream inputStream = EmailMessages.class.getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("/sample.html");
```

Comment: try getContext().getResourceAsStream("/_Pagestest/_HtmlFiles/_sample.html");

Comment: Please don't use [java] tag as long as problem is not demonstratable using plain Java application class with main() method, nor is answerable with the JLS. You will only get knee-jerk "answers" from users/plagiarists who think to be good at Googling.

Answer (score 1):

The root folder is on the classpath, so try this one:

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Pages/HtmlFiles/sample.html");
```

Comment: even this returning null.i used classname.class instead of this.

Comment: how are you running your application?

Comment: Application is deployed in jboss server

Answer (score -1):

Place you files in `src\main\resources` folder and when you export a war you can find your files in the `resources` directory under `WEB-INF\classes` folder. Now read the html file like this,

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Pages/html/index.html");
```

Comment: its asking to create class for fileloader?

Comment: @Downvoter Care to explain what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: It returns null.Here instead of this i used classname.class because it was showing me error.

Comment: @dafodil Do you have the Pages folder under the `WEB-INF/classes/resources` directory?

Comment: its in war folder of project not in WEB-INF, i need to get path of sample.html file that is in war file of server.